# Get files stored in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, sdk, adb, genymotion

Hi I want to install apk's via Google Play Store in a genymotion emulator and then get the apk with adb commands. The problem is adb does not recognize my virtual devices when I execute `adb devices`. I handled all the SDK problems with Genymotion (Genymotion uses its own SDK) I used a custom Android SDK.

I know that Android applications are stored in /data/app/ and `adb` allows us to access this folder for an emulator or a rooted phone, how can I get data I need ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're not insisting on using ADB commands, i suggest that you can alternatively place the APK in a shared directory with you PC ... to do so open your virtual device settings from virtual box and set your shared directory

See the attached image

[image]

In your virtual device you'll find this directory in root /mnt/shared